# Error while communicating the Client with TranslationManagerFacade service | web 8

Tags: workflow, translation-manager, web8

I am sending a component inside to the Translation Manager (SDL World Server) using the workflow In which I am calling a TranslationManagerFacade Service to communicate with Translation Manager System.
I am trying to call the method inside TranslationManagerFacade service from the client and getting the error below.

> ERROR Workflow.SendTranslationActivityWorker - **System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException:** The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '00:00:59.9990004'. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
>      at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.ReadCore(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout, Boolean closing)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>
> **Server stack trace:**
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.ReadCore(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout, Boolean closing)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.DelegatingConnection.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel.SendPreamble(IConnection connection, ArraySegment`1 preamble, TimeoutHelper& timeoutHelper)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel.DuplexConnectionPoolHelper.AcceptPooledConnection(IConnection connection, TimeoutHelper& timeoutHelper)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionPoolHelper.EstablishConnection(TimeSpan timeout)

I increased the timeout to 3 minutes but it still reports the `CommunicationException`.

Here is my client code to create the endpoint (I've confirmed I can hit the service over http)

Here is the line of code where the error is generated

```
public string Translate(string UserId, string title, string publicationId, IEnumerable<string> items, bool includeItemsAlreadyTranslated)
{
    string tcpServiceUrl = "net.tcp//MyMachineName:808/TranslationManagerFacade.svc"
    NetTcpBinding tcpb = new NetTcpBinding();
    tcpb.Security = new NetTcpSecurity() { Mode = SecurityMode.None };
    channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<ITranslation>(tcpb);
    endpoint = new EndpointAddress(tcpServiceUrl);
    client = channelFactory.CreateChannel(endpoint);

    return client.Translate(UserId, title, publicationId, items, includeItemsAlreadyTranslated);   
}
```

I am following the blog from [Eric Huiza](https://community.sdl.com/products-solutions/solutions/customer_experience_cloud/digital-experience/tridion/tridion-developer/b/weblog/archive/2015/02/27/sdl-tridion-workflow-translation-manager-integration) to implement `TranslationManagerFacade`

Here is the endpoint in `TranslationManagerFacade`

[image]

service is hosted in IIS on the same machine.
I can see that client is not null in my code

Answer (score 1):

Since you are on SDL Web 8, you really shouldn't use the TranslationManagerFacade, as it is based on a deprecated API. Besides being deprecated it is also limited in functionality compared to the new API - and it is a lot harder to use.

You can find the documentation for the new API here:
http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-62FCD244-8E86-48DD-8569-86A9EDBFA7A5

Answer (score 0):

The Issue has been resolved by changing the service name from

```
<service behaviorConfiguration="" name="TranslationManagerFacade"> to 
 <service behaviorConfiguration=""
 name="TranslationManagerFacade.TranslationManagerFacade">
```

in the web.config file of TranslationManagerFacade service.